# document.body.scrollTop is always 0 in IE even when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am displaying the value of document.body.scrollTop in the status bar  while moving the mouse. The value is always 0 in IE. Why is always 0? Is there another way to get how much the scroll bar has moved?

Comment: I upvoted the selected answer since no one else seemed to have done it ( unless there was a downvote to counter it ). It would have been nice if you had responded to Nick's question.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You may want to try this for an older doctype in IE:

```
var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
              document.body.scrollTop;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that bomb if `document.documentElement` is undefined? I think you meant `document.documentElement` instead of `document.documentElement.scrollTop` in the first part of the ternary expression. :)

Comment: @Vivin - It's not undefined, the scroll property just isn't set, resulting in 0/false.

Comment: This can be abbreviated to `var top = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;`

Comment: You thought you could do a simple || operation?  Chuck Testa.  If you try to access the documentElement's property .scrollTop, it will blow.  Best (read: non-explosive) solution:  `var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;`

Comment: Be careful using document.documentElement.scrollTop in iOS. It will always report 0. If you need to actually test for scrollTop==0 then this switch won't work.

Comment: There's also now `document.scrollingElement`. I'm using the result of `document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement`, at least until I find somewhere that doesn't work.

Comment: This fixes the problem in Safari too, having the same issue there, document.documentElement.scrollTop always reports 0

Answer (score 16):

this function provides a cross-browser implementation of reading the scroll offset:

```
function posTop() {
            return typeof window.pageYOffset != 'undefined' ? window.pageYOffset: document.documentElement.scrollTop? document.documentElement.scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop? document.body.scrollTop:0;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only answer that works in both older versions of IE as newest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the DOCTYPE, you would have to use `document.body.scrollTop` or `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. Have you tried the second one?

You can do something like this:

```
var scrollTop = document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop :
                                           document.body.scrollTop;
```

I ran into these links while researching your problem:

- [Window size and scrolling](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) (towards the bottom)
- [document.body.scrollTop in IE](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=11965)

This may help you out a little more.