# onscroll won't work with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, onscroll

i have a "body" with `onScroll="Scroll()"`. Scroll method should, well, scroll some div as user scrolls the page.

Scroll():

```
function Scroll()
{
    var el = document.getElementById('controlBox');
    var ScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    el.style.top = ScrollTop + "px";
}
```

It works fine with Chrome and FF, but IE won't cooperate. What's wrong here?

Comment: have you consider  `position: fixed` ?

Comment: No, i have to use relative, because "controlbox" has to be on the right side of the window, and some number of pixels away from the top.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the onScroll from your body tag, and try adding

```
window.onscroll = Scroll;
```

to your javascript, outside of the function.

Comment: Well, now function "Scroll()" gets called, but div is not moving :\

Comment: Your div isn't moving because `document.body.scrollTop` doesn't exist in IE. Please see this question for a solution to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling