# scrollTop and doctype

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for at solution to make document.body.scrollTop return the right values when using a doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

now this only works with chrome and not in ff and ie

```
alert('scrollTop = '+document.body.scrollTop);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.body.scrollTop is always 0 in IE even when scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling)

Comment: but it works fine in ie if you remove the doctype tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the two alternatives:

```
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```