# Keeping header element always on top when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I've read numerous articles on this topic and tried implementing a few, but I just can't seem to get it right. I have a simple HTML table, which compares products:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Product:</th>
    <th>Product 1</th>
    <th>Product 2</th>
    <th>Product 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Features</td>
    <td>Product 1 features</td>
    <td>Product 2 features</td>
    <td>Product 3 features</td>
   </tr>
   and so the list goes on...
 </table>
```

What I want is for the header row to always be on top of the active window, that is the top row when I scroll down, since my rows go down quite far. I want to keep the product names in the  tags always visible so that a user can relate the content to the different products in the very top row all the time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/983031/214773

Comment: @JúlioSantos: No, **this** question doesn't mention jQuery (or even JavaScript) at all.

Comment: Oh, OK, point taken. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I simple technique is to have the header row in a separate `table` from the actual data.
This header table is set to have it's position as `fixed`, and then the table below, which holds the results, has it's `margin-top` set the `height` of the header table.

This creates the effect of the header staying where it is and the table scrolling.

A basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zKDR4/2/

You can also create a fixed header with jQuery plugins. Take a look at this one http://fixedheadertable.com/ really simple to implement.

**Edit**

As Anders has mentioned, if you go down my suggested route, you will need to set the widths of the `th` and `td` elements. Otherwise they would not match up since they are separate tables.

Comment: This will not work well if the widths of th and td differ, which they usually do. If the cells (including headers) have a fixed and equal size, this works very well however. (+1 still, best solution I think, and also nice jquery tip)

Comment: @AndersHolmström yeah you need to set the widths of the `th` and `td` in this case. Best solution I feel though is using a jquery plugin which builds the header table from the table so that the widths are correct.

Comment: Good answer thanks, it works well. However, when viewed on a small screen (mobile screen) , you have to scroll horizontally. Now that poses a problem, since when you scroll horizontally, the fixed header scrolls horizontal as well(since it is fixed, and it partly out of the window). How do I only fix it vertically?

Comment: For a mobile screen I would try to get rid of the horizontal scrolling. Look into Responsive CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem for a planning with row headers (hours) and column headers (days).
I wanted to keep visible the both.
The application shows the content in an IFrame, so I've created an horizontal DIV and a vertical DIV outside the IFrame with a style "overflow:hidden". 
Then I've synchronized the scrollings with the "onscroll" event of the IFrame.

Here is my code to synchronize headers with scrolling:

```
window.onscroll = function () {

        try {
            // - Scroll days header (on the top) horizontally
            var offsetX = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) || document.body.scrollLeft; // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling
            var header1Div = window.parent.document.getElementById("EntetesColonnes");
            header1Div.scrollLeft = offsetX;

            // - Scroll hours header (on the left) vertically 
            var offsetY = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop; // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling
            var header2Div = window.parent.document.getElementById("HeaderHoursLeft");
            header2Div.scrollTop = offsetY;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert("FrmPlanningChirurgien/window.onscroll: " + ex.message);
        }
    }
```

My solution is not that simple, because I had to set in "onresize" the width of horizontal DIV and the height of vertical DIV.
Then this induces more complexity, because onResize could be fired a lot of times per second, and this event is even fired in IE8 when scrolling occurs.
So I've done a setTimeout to prevent headers to be redrawn too often :

```
var PREVIOUS_frameWidth = 0;
var PREVIOUS_frameHeight = 0;
var timerMakeHeaders = null;

window.onresize = function () {
    try {

        var frameWidth = CROSS.getWindowWidth();
        var frameHeight = CROSS.getWindowHeight();

        if (frameWidth != PREVIOUS_frameWidth || frameHeight != PREVIOUS_frameHeight) {

            // - *** Launch headers creation method
            // - If there is another query to redraw, the Timer is stopped and recreated.
            // - The headers are only redrawn when Timer fires.
            if (timerMakeHeaders != null) {
                window.clearTimeout(timerMakeHeaders);
                timerMakeHeaders = null;
            }
            timerMakeHeaders = window.setTimeout(makeHeaders, 50); 

            // - *** Store new values
            PREVIOUS_frameWidth = frameWidth;
            PREVIOUS_frameHeight = frameHeight;
        }
    } catch (e) { alert("Erreur window.onresize/FrmPlanningChirurgien.aspx : " + e.message); }
}
```

And finally the `makeHeaders()` method have to resize DIVs :

```
function makeHeaders() {

    // (...)

    var frame = window.parent.document.getElementById("CalendarFrame"); 
    var iframeRect = frame.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    headerDiv.style.width = iframeRect.right - iframeRect.left - 20; // The 20 pixels are here for the vertical scrollbar width
    headerDiv.scrollLeft = frame.scrollLeft;

    // (...)


    var headerHourDiv = window.parent.document.getElementById("HeaderHoursLeft");
    var newHeight = iframeRect.bottom - iframeRect.top - 20 - 7; // The VISIBLE width for the DIV must be equal to IFRAME Width minus the scroll width or height
    headerHourDiv.style.height = newHeight; 
    headerHourDiv.scrollTop = frame.scrollTop;       


}
catch (e) {
    alert("makeHeaders: " + e.message);
}    }
```

Perhaps it could be possible not to use an IFRAME, and to use only 3 DIVS: one for each header, and the last one for the content. But the mechanism have to be the same I think : needs a synchronization between scrolling positions.

Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

I have created an example using JSFiddle, which you can [view as a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BpLsR/).

The only downside is that you will need to specify column sizes as when you use `position: fixed` you lose the widths on the header.

This is the CSS for the example, the HTML is the same as that you have supplied.

```
thead {
    height: 1em;
}

thead tr {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by make a div and fix the position . or it can also done by adding inline css

```
<table style="position:fixed;">
  <tr>
     <th>Product:</th>
     <th>Product 1</th>
     <th>Product 2</th>
      <th>Product 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Features</td>
     <td>Product 1 features</td>
     <td>Product 2 features</td>
     <td>Product 3 features</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This does not do what the question asks.  It just fixes the whole table to one place on the page.