# how to fix a division using css and js..?

Tags: javascript, css

In my webpage a division in the left hand side should be fixed in a particular position.I am using `position:fixed;top:150px;left:0px;`. So now even we scrolldown the page the division will not change from the current position.

But here i am facing a problem. If am scrolling down the page `150px or more` i am getting the white space of `150px` at the top of that left hand side division.

So what my requirement is if am scrolling down the page `150px or more` then the css of that left hand side division should be changed to `position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;` and as well as when i am going to top of the page again the css should change to `position:fixed;top:150px;left:0px`;

I came to know that this can't be done with only CSS and we have to use JS along with the CSS. But i don't know how to do that.

Please help me...!!

Thanks in advance,
Sreeram

Comment: can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ for this please?

Comment: Use position:relative to achieve what you are trying

Comment: @ericosg : Ya sure wait a min..!

Comment: You can refer this this  and example links given in answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972643/keeping-header-element-always-on-top-when-scrolling

Comment: @ ericosg http://jsfiddle.net/MvQ6y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based of what you said above you want to have an element follow you down the page but change it's top position after you scroll down a little ways.

I've created a jsfiddle that uses js to add a class to an element once the document is scrolled past 150px. It also removes that class if they scroll back above 150px.

http://jsfiddle.net/KQCRC/

```
.fix {
    position:fixed;
    top:150px;
    left:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#fff;
}
.fix.scrolled {
top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much........!!  Its perfectly working now....!!..Once again thanks a lot..!!