# Simple javascript does not work in any IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am creating a slight minor parallax effect with this code.Everything works fine everywhere,except IE.I am using IE 9.

[Jsfiddle-javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/MRbWY/1/)

[Jsfiddle-jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfd2R/)

```
<div id="head"> i </div>
<div id="subHead"> can </div>
<div id="content">  haz </div>
```

Javascript

```
window.onscroll = function(ev){
  var subHead = document.getElementById('subHead'),
      topHeight = document.getElementById('head').offsetHeight;

  subHead.style.top = (topHeight - document.body.scrollTop / 4) + 'px';
};
```

CSS

```
#head, #subHead{
    position: fixed;           
    height: 80px;    
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #c00;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

#subHead{
    z-index: 4;
    background: #cd0; 
    top: 80px;
}

#content{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #eee;
    margin-top: 160px;
}
```

i tried googling some cross browser tricks,but in vain...Is there any way to make it work in IE ?thanks a lot.

**Edit:**

Purpose: To make a 1 div move slower than another when a user scrolls.

Logic:make the div fixed via css and change its postion via javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/MRbWY/11/

Error in IE.The javascript doesnt work.hence the div remains only fixed

Comment: What errors do you get in IE's developer console?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: in IE,the word "can" is fixed......which it should not be coz of javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that in the fiddle.

Comment: here is a more visible example.... http://www.ilovetrolls.org/ the logo is moving in chrome,but in IE it stays fixed..

Comment: I've been looking over your code for about twenty mins now and you have me stumped.  I deleted my non-answer answer in hopes someone else will be enticed to give you a better one.

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly in your post.

Comment: *Latest version* is ambiguous. It's IE10 on Win8 and IE9 on Win7.

Comment: ok,sorry,updated my post.

Comment: Just an FYI - I am using IE8, and it is not fixed. It scrolls.

Comment: hey,@jamesemanon,are you sure? plz can you scroll here  with IE8  IE8.http://ilovetrolls.org/   ?the logo shall move in IE8,if all is fine?

Comment: @Zeta - actually, IE10 is now available for Win7. However, most people will still be using IE9 for the time being.

Comment: @SDC: I know, but as far as I know it isn't distributed yet in Windows Update, or is it?

Comment: @Zeta: for the time being it's an optional update, but it is available. I hear they're planning to move it to auto-update fairly quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

document.body.scrollTop was always reading zero, a bit of digging turns up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling), you want to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for IE.

[updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh2Gb/1/)