# body.scrollTop is not working in firefox and IE When inside Blogger

Tags: javascript, scroll, document, blogger

Here is a JavaScript. This is working good in chrome but not working in Firefox and IE when it is inside blogger

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > 5) {
          var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];
          header.className = "header down"
}
```

and i have also trie it

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop > 5) {
          var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];
          header.className = "header down"
        }
```

Please tell how it will work in Firefox and IE. Please only JavaScript and No J Query.

Comment: No errors in firefox, ie?

Comment: but then why it is not working. Please chek it on my website where it is taken http://www.softwarewing.co.vu/

Comment: on edge (windows 10 IE) it's working, but your website is too heavy on effects, on average pc it will run slowly

Comment: For me it's working!

Comment: @MozzieMD Do you visit my website and see if window scroll down then its header give a change

Comment: Yes i checked, it's working, and you used too much javascript!

Answer (score 4):

I've had a look at your website javascript and can see that in IE and Firefox, `document.body.scrollTop` is always 0. See [document.body.scrollTop is always 0 in IE even when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling).

Therefore, `down` will never get added to your header div. You will need to use a combination of `document.body.scrollTop` or `document.documentElement.scrollTop` depending on the browser in use.

Comment: what is for the firefox

Comment: This is the same for Firefox, you will have to use document.documentElement.scrollTop.

Comment: @syedMuhammadAsad Please mark as the answer if this fixes your problem.

Comment: The problem is coming in my template which is on blogger. This function is not working in firefox when it is inside blogger. But it work well when it is not inside blogger.