# Jquery issue on IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

The following jquery code works just fine on the latest version of Chrome,

On focus event of the input field it should trigger the autocompletion of the field itself using ajax to retrieve the suggestions but it does not work at all on IE10

The console is empty...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
  $(function() {

    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

     $( "#myBut").click(function(){

     if($('#city').val() == "")
     return;

     log("selected: " + $("#city").val() );

     $('#city').val("");
     $('#city').blur("");

     });

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8085/TestJsonArrayAJAX/MyServlet",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {

            alert("ciao");
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 0,
      select: function( event, ui )
      {

          alert('ccc');

      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }}).focus(function() {    alert("c"); 
            //Use the below line instead of triggering keydown
            $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").search($(this).val()) });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="city">Your city: </label>
  <input id="city">
  Powered by <a href="http://geonames.org">geonames.org</a>

</div>

<button name="subject" id="myBut" value="HTML">HTML</button>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console? It should *always* be the first thing you do when you have a JS issue. Even then some description of what is/is not happening would be much appreciated. Simply stating 'it doesn't work' helps no one, least of all you.

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with `scrollTop` on IE. Might this help? [document.body.scrollTop is always 0 in IE even when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717252/document-body-scrolltop-is-always-0-in-ie-even-when-scrolling)

Comment: unfortunately it's not that...I should see suggestions when the input field is onfocus but I don't.