# Position of Page - Fill a navigation bar on the side depending on position

Tags: jquery, html, navigation

I know there are a lot of tools in place like scrollspy from bootstrap or watching what `section` or `div` you're on and highlighting linked navigation sections, but what I'm looking for is slightly different. Is there a jQuery method that calculates the position on the page so I can show where on the page you are in relation to the whole thing? I'm not fluent enough in jQuery.

Could I calculate the height of the page and divide it out of where I'm at on the page (current position) to give me a percentage so I can continuously show my position? Are there methods available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Methods:
scrollTop() - returns current vertical position of scrollbar

height() - returns computed height for first matched element

You may want to show 100% when user is at end of page.

So you can use following to get percentage:

($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height())/$(document).height()) * 100

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the code from this answer: [Cross-Browser Method to Determine Vertical Scroll Percentage in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript#answer-8028584)

You could do this.  You would replace console.log with whatever code you need to update something on the screen.

```
$(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(window).height();
    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;

    console.log("Current scroll percent: " + scrollPercent);
  });
});
```