# find percentage of page height jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write code to a div telling a user how far he has scrolled down the page. Here is my code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

var fullHeight = $(this).height();

var currentHeight = $(this).scrollTop();

var percentageOfPage = currentHeight/fullHeight;

percentageOfPage = percentageOfPage.toFixed(2);

var t = $("#t");
t.html("You are " + percentageOfPage + " down this page." );


});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/8hpaLek6/)
The code works mostly how it should: it writes out the percentage how far a user has scrolled. But it stops at about .67 or .69. Why does it do that? I want it to go all the way to 1. Also, how can I display it as a percentage, like 60%, instead of a decimal, like .6? [here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/files/stories/js/height_test) is where the page is.

**ADDITION**:
How can I make it so that at the when the user reaches the bottom of the page, the message becomes: "You have reached the bottom of the page", instead of the percentage?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8hpaLek6/2/  From there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript

Comment: @A.Wolff, put that in an answer, it's the only one that works. :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('scroll.percentage', function() {
  var scrollPercent = Math.round(100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()));
  // if the user has reached the bottom of the page
  // unbind the scroll listener
  if (scrollPercent == 100) {
    $("#t").html("You have reached the bottom of the page.");
    $(this).off('scroll.percentage');
    return;
  }
  $("#t").html("You are " + scrollPercent + "% down this page.");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#t {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t"></div>
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the addition

Comment: @yak613 how about now?

Comment: yes, this works, but is there a way to make it stay as "you have reached the bottom of the page", instead of reverting to a percentage when the user scrolls back up?

Comment: @yak613 So, once the user reaches the bottom of the page, and scrolls back up, the message should still be "you have reached the bottom of the page"? Try it now.

Answer (score 6):

You should bind `scroll` event to `window` object, and then use following logic: (found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028584/1414562))

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(this).height();
    scrollPercent = ((s / (d - c)) * 100).toFixed(2);

    console.log("Current scroll percent: " + scrollPercent);

    var t = $("#t");
    t.html(scrollPercent != 100 ? "You are " + scrollPercent + "% down this page." : "You have reached the bottom of the page");

  }) /*.scroll() to trigger event on load*/ ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t" style="position:fixed; top:0px;"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: (d - c) was critical ... ":)

Answer (score 0):

> Also, how can I display it as a percentage, like 60%

```
var percentageOfPage = currentHeight/fullHeight*100;
...
t.html("You are " + percentageOfPage + "% down this page." );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will always calculate from the top or bottom of the viewport, there will be a percentage to start or end.

This should work

```
var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop()/($(document).height() - $(window).height());
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/8hpaLek6/