# Show div before 200% of page and hide after

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

How Can I make value in "%". I want to get dive show before 200% of the site and hide after. Thanks for any advice!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > {percent:200})
     {
        $('.box').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.box').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

Comment: **Java != JavaScript**. It even says so right there in the tooltips!!!!!!

Comment: 200% of what? You mean like where the top of the page is 0% and the bottom of the page is 100%? If so, how do people scroll past the end of the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Browser Method to Determine Vertical Scroll Percentage in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript)

Comment: Not quite a perfect dup, but looking at [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028584/1270789), probably `var over200percent = (h[st]||b[st] > h.clientHeight * 2);` is close to what the OP wants, detecting when the user scrolls two pages worth?

Comment: `if ($(this).scrollTop() > {percent:200})` - you compare the result of `scrollTop()` with the object literal, which is wrong.

Comment: 200% mean that I have got many sections in page. Each of it got 100% height. It doesn't matter for me its visible from top but just hidden past section "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply height with 2 for 200%

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(this).height() * 2){
    $('.box').fadeOut();
  }
  else{
    $('.box').fadeIn();
  }
});
```