# Get scroll percentage between 0 and 1 when scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have looked at multiple formulas for getting the window offset where when scrolled to the top the offset is `0` and when scrolled to the bottom the offset is the `offsetHeight`. None have worked. Some give `0` when at the top but not the right height when at the bottom and vise versa.

This is the closest I have gotten:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', setBackgroundColor)

function setBackgroundColor() {
  let offset = (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) / document.body.offsetHeight
  console.log(offset, window.innerHeight + window.scrollY, document.body.offsetHeight)
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 500vh;
}
```

The closest I have gotten to zero is `0.2`, but the height works fine. What would the formula be for getting `0` and `scrollHeight`?

Comment: The [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript) worked for me, but simplified to `let offset = window.scrollY/ (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve 0 in a division, you need to left side of the operator to be equal to 0 (0 divided by anything is always 0). In your case, it is always equal to something higher than 0 since you are doing an addition of a number always larger than 0 and another one that is >= than 0.

Try dividing the scroll position with the document height minus the window scroll:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', setBackgroundColor)

function setBackgroundColor() {
  let offset = window.scrollY / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight)
  console.log(offset, window.innerHeight + window.scrollY, document.body.offsetHeight)
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 500vh;
}
```

Comment: You still get more than 1 if the bottom of the page.

Comment: Depends on the context, I agree with your answer that `document.body.scrollHeight` is better, but both can result in the same value and achieve the same thing. I use the OP formula in this context and the output must not be the same in every browser since in Firefox, it is always between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

One slight difference from Karl-André Gagnon solution (because as I commented, it gets more than 1 in the bottom of the page). use `document.body.scrollHeight` instead of `document.body.offsetHeight`:

```
let offset = window.scrollY / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)
```