# Scroll by given vertical scroll percentage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, cross-browser

I have `X` and `Y` scroll values in percentage (values spanning from 0 to 100) and I want to scroll the page to that location. I am receiving the percentage values from an API call.

```js
function scrollPageByGivenPercentage(percentageX, percentageY) {
    // ... scroll by percentage ...
    //window.scrollTo(percentageX, percentageY);
}
```

The above function scrolls in pixels and it doesn't do the job. What I tried using is this:

```js
function scrollPageByGivenPercentage(percentageX, percentageY) {
    var yScrollInPx = document.body.documentElement.clientHeight * percentageY;
    window.scrollTo(0, yScrollInPx);
}
```

My guess is `clientHeight` is the wrong property. Tried `offsetHeight` as well.

I get the calculate the percentages from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript):

I have this function to receive the current scroll value in percentage:

```js
function getScrollPercent() {
    var h = document.documentElement,
        b = document.body,
        st = 'scrollTop',
        sh = 'scrollHeight';
    return (h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the total height of the document, work out the percentage you need in `px` then apply that to `window.scrollTo()`. Try this:

```js
var scrollYPercent = 0.25;
var scrollYPx = document.documentElement.scrollHeight * scrollYPercent;
window.scrollTo(0, scrollYPx);
```

```css
html, body { height: 1000px; }
p { margin-top: 400px; }
```

```html
<p>Note the scroll position -></p>
```

Comment: Totally forgot about `scrollHeight ` property.  :)