# Scroll to a specific point on a webpage given a percentage

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm using [the following function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028584/7663202) to calculate and save the percentage of how much of a web page I have scrolled:

```
const getPercentRead = () => {
  const h = document.documentElement,
    b = document.body,
    st = "scrollTop",
    sh = "scrollHeight";
  return ((h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight)) * 100;
}
```

After refreshing the page, I want to use the output of this function and the current window height to scroll myself to the last saved location.

This is my current attempt at doing this:

```
const scrolled = (percentRead / windowHeight) * 100;
window.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
```

However, this does not take me to the correct scroll position. I'd appreciate any help you can give on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use percentages, this solution will work.

Save this value:

```
var x = window.pageYOffset;
```

Then scroll to it:

```
window.scrollTo(0, x);
```

Comment: Right. The issue is I will need to turn it into a percentage for use in the UI. I also like the idea of saving a percentage, because I may come back to view the webpage on a different device, so saving the pageYOffset won't work there.