# Referencing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, reference

so I have the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

// Get a reference to the <path>
var path = document.querySelector('#star-path');

// Get length of path... ~577px in this case
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

// Make very long dashes (the length of the path itself)
path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;

// Offset the dashes so the it appears hidden entirely
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

// Jake Archibald says so
// https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/
path.getBoundingClientRect();

// When the page scrolls...
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
 
  // What % down is it? 
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript/2387222#2387222
  // Had to try three or four differnet methods here. Kind of a cross-browser nightmare.
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    
  // Length to offset the dashes
  var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
  
  // Draw in reverse
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
    
  // When complete, remove the dash array, otherwise shape isn't quite sharp
 // Accounts for fuzzy math
  if (scrollPercentage >= 0.99) {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "none";
    path.style.fill = "#47AF9A";
    
  } else {
  path.style.fill = "none";
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
  }
  
});
});
```

```css
body {
  /* feel free to change height */
  height: 5000px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    orange,
    darkblue
  );
}

h1 {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

#star-svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}



Resources
```

```html
<header>
  
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</header>
  
  <body>
  <h1>Scroll-to-draw</h1>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200.6" id="star-svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="star-path" d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z"></svg>
  </body>
```

This code works here perfectly fine but it does not work on the IDE I am working in, like when I scroll, I do not get the lines to draw but it just shows the overall output which is the H letter. Could you guys please take a look here: https://repl.it/join/xfuwhnru-hussainomer

P.S. You might need to make an account as it is `repl.it` but could you guys please help me out with this? The problem that I can think of is that I am missing a reference in my code over there, it works here because StackOverFlow **creates** a reference but not every IDE does. Any Suggestions?

Comment: And the IDE you are using is?

Comment: repl.it is the ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the code on codepen.io for a quick check and it works fine there. Is it only with the project so that it does not work with the IDE?

Comment: It does not run on the link I shared