# Same Code Does Not Work In A Different IDE - html,css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

so I have the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

// Get a reference to the <path>
var path = document.querySelector('#star-path');

// Get length of path... ~577px in this case
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

// Make very long dashes (the length of the path itself)
path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;

// Offset the dashes so the it appears hidden entirely
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

// Jake Archibald says so
// https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/
path.getBoundingClientRect();

// When the page scrolls...
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
 
  // What % down is it? 
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387136/cross-browser-method-to-determine-vertical-scroll-percentage-in-javascript/2387222#2387222
  // Had to try three or four differnet methods here. Kind of a cross-browser nightmare.
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    
  // Length to offset the dashes
  var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
  
  // Draw in reverse
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
    
  // When complete, remove the dash array, otherwise shape isn't quite sharp
 // Accounts for fuzzy math
  if (scrollPercentage >= 0.99) {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "none";
    path.style.fill = "#47AF9A";
    
  } else {
  path.style.fill = "none";
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
  }
  
});
});
```

```css
body {
  /* feel free to change height */
  height: 5000px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    orange,
    darkblue
  );
}

h1 {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

#star-svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}



Resources
```

```html
<header>
  
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</header>
  
  <body>
  <h1>Scroll-to-draw</h1>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200.6" id="star-svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="star-path" d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z"></svg>
  </body>
```

This code works here perfectly fine but it does not work on the IDE I am working in, like when I scroll, I do not get the lines to draw but it just shows the overall output which is the H letter. Could you guys please take a look here: https://repl.it/join/xfuwhnru-hussainomer

P.S. You might need to make an account as it is `repl.it` but could you guys please take a look at it, it will be really helpful and I would really appreciate it. The problem that I can think of is that I am missing a reference in my code over there, it works here because StackOverFlow **creates** a reference but not every IDE does. Any Suggestions?

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: `Repl.it` is the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed:

view-source:https://fixedstingytriangle--hussainomer.repl.co/

It is the following, and *only* the following:

```
<header>
  
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</header>
  
  <body>
  <h1>Scroll-to-draw</h1>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200.6" id="star-svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="star-path" d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z"></svg>
  </body>
```

- You do not have a DOCTYPE
- You do not have a `<html>` tag
- You have a `<header>`, but a `<header>` is a visible element which should only be inside the `<body>`. You probably meant to use `<head>` instead.

Fix those issues, and the code works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
... etc
</head>
<body>
... etc
```

The most important thing here is to explicitly specify a doctype. [Without it](https://medium.com/@heitorhherzog/what-happens-when-you-remove-doctype-from-the-html-page-b062e6a0beec):

> The browser enters Quirks mode and tries to deal with your code as if it was written in the late 90’s. This means they will imitate many bugs that existed in the old browsers. It is not consistent on how to do this (so you will get significantly different results, for example, from Firefox to Internet Explorer).

> The purpose of DOCTYPE is to tell the browser what type of HTML you are writing. It is not valid to omit the DOCTYPE. There is no “Standard” format. The browser will just try to parse HTML as best it can. But not all elements will be displayed correctly. DOCTYPE is a required part of all HTML documents.

which, here, causes problems because the `document.documentElement.clientHeight` will be evaluated as the height of the whole page, rather than the height of the viewport (resulting in division by 0 and the whole H appearing immediately)