# Animate text fill that correlates with scroll percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate the progression of a text fill color that correlates with the scroll percentage in the browser. IE) text fill is animated from left to right along with the scroll percentage, and it unfills as you scroll back up from that section. I'm not super familiar with JS, but I've seen someone do this with event listeners.

I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, as SO isn't a code writing service I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scroll event to colorize your words.
The main idea is to use the scroll position to define how many words need to be colored, you can refine the colorize part based on your needs.
The bigger the body is the slower your text will be colorized.

```js
const HIGHLIGHT = 'class="highlight"';
const TEXT = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer suscipit libero eu ligula molestie, sed faucibus leo iaculis. Quisque scelerisque ligula in volutpat venenatis. Fusce velit felis, pretium eu varius quis, facilisis eget nunc. Quisque eu eros tellus. Cras condimentum efficitur turpis, ac laoreet velit rhoncus et. Maecenas non lorem auctor dolor auctor gravida ut at diam. Proin eleifend elementum lacus in varius. In dapibus mi ut erat gravida, non dictum nisi luctus. Aliquam imperdiet commodo ante, posuere vestibulum eros mattis vitae. Cras molestie commodo turpis, vitae tempus magna dictum pharetra. Duis quis eros at magna sodales mollis. Fusce sollicitudin purus sit amet est ullamcorper luctus. Donec molestie, nisi quis luctus malesuada, lectus arcu rutrum turpis, ac bibendum libero tellus at metus. Vivamus mattis ultricies metus eu dignissim. Mauris sed consectetur nisl."
let words = TEXT.split(" ");
let text = document.querySelector('.text');
text.innerHTML = words
  .map(w => `<span>${w}</span>`)
  .join(' ');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let scroll = getScrollFraction();
  let words_highlighted = scroll * words.length;
  
  text.innerHTML = words
  .map((w, i) => `<span ${i < words_highlighted ? HIGHLIGHT : ''}>${w}</span>`)
  .join(' ');
})

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028584/2931840
//
function getScrollFraction() {
    var h = document.documentElement, 
        b = document.body,
        st = 'scrollTop',
        sh = 'scrollHeight';
    return (h[st]||b[st]) / ((h[sh]||b[sh]) - h.clientHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

.highlight {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <span class="text"></span>
</body>
</html>
```